# Parsing JSON with a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to check if there's a username available when `type = account` by parsing the key **"Entities"**. If not available, get the IP from `type = ip`

```
data = '[\n    {\n        "TimeRecorded": "2020-09-20T08:56:12Z",\n        "AlertName": "Alert1",\n        "Entities": "[\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Address\\": \\"160.160.100.2\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"ip\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"4\\",\\r\\n    \\"DnsDomain\\": \\"example.com\\",\\r\\n    \\"HostName\\": \\"MyMachine1\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"host\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"5\\",\\r\\n    \\"Name\\": \\"Tenant1\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"account\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n]"\n    },\n    {\n        "TimeRecorded": "2020-09-20T07:56:13Z",\n        "AlertName": "Alert2",\n        "Entities": "[\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Address\\": \\"160.160.100.1\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"ip\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"4\\",\\r\\n    \\"DnsDomain\\": \\"example.com\\",\\r\\n    \\"HostName\\": \\"MyMachine2\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"host\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"5\\",\\r\\n    \\"Name\\": \\"Tenant2\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"account\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n]"\n    },\n    {\n        "TimeRecorded": "2020-09-20T05:56:14Z",\n        "AlertName": "Alert3",\n        "Entities": "[\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Address\\": \\"160.160.100.3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"ip\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"4\\",\\r\\n    \\"DnsDomain\\": \\"example.com\\",\\r\\n    \\"HostName\\": \\"MyMachine3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"host\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"5\\",\\r\\n    \\"Name\\": \\"Tenant3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"account\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n]"\n    }\n]'
```

I attempted to use a couple of for loops for `data['Entities'][0]` but either getting `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` or `[`. What would be the neat way to access the values in each entity?

```
for i in data:
     print(i['Entities'])
```

Comment: Where did you get the data, and did you do anything to it before you posted it? It's JSON containing encoded JSON...

Comment: `data` is a string, not a json structure. you probably want to start by parsing that json

Comment: @mkrieger1 Not at all. I guess it's because of the unstructured data and that I tried all suggestions here and still got errors such as `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to parse this oddly-structured JSON twice.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

newdata = json.loads(data) # creates dict with some embedded JSON
for alert in newdata:
    alert["Entities"] = json.loads(alert["Entities"])

pprint(newdata)
```

yields

```
[{'AlertName': 'Alert1',
  'Entities': [{'$id': '3', 'Address': '160.160.100.2', 'Type': 'ip'},
               {'$id': '4',
                'DnsDomain': 'example.com',
                'HostName': 'MyMachine1',
                'Type': 'host'},
               {'$id': '5', 'Name': 'Tenant1', 'Type': 'account'}],
  'TimeRecorded': '2020-09-20T08:56:12Z'},
 {'AlertName': 'Alert2',
  'Entities': [{'$id': '3', 'Address': '160.160.100.1', 'Type': 'ip'},
               {'$id': '4',
                'DnsDomain': 'example.com',
                'HostName': 'MyMachine2',
                'Type': 'host'},
               {'$id': '5', 'Name': 'Tenant2', 'Type': 'account'}],
  'TimeRecorded': '2020-09-20T07:56:13Z'},
 {'AlertName': 'Alert3',
  'Entities': [{'$id': '3', 'Address': '160.160.100.3', 'Type': 'ip'},
               {'$id': '4',
                'DnsDomain': 'example.com',
                'HostName': 'MyMachine3',
                'Type': 'host'},
               {'$id': '5', 'Name': 'Tenant3', 'Type': 'account'}],
  'TimeRecorded': '2020-09-20T05:56:14Z'}]
```

Please note that the numbers in the `"$id"` fields are stored as text, so if you need those values you'll need to use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) on them.

Comment: It popped up this error: `raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string: `. I just hope that there's a way to loop through anything under `Entities` and get `Name` if there's one available.

Comment: @HieDop My code works with the data you posted in the question without an errors - I copied it directly out of the REPL I used to test it. If you are using different data or different code, please ask a new question, making sure to include the data you're using and the full text of the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through `data` (assuming already it's in JSON form) and process the entities key using `json.loads` for each time your iterate. (As right now, your data is in string form)

```
import json
for d in data:
    processed = json.loads(d['Entities'])  # returns an array of dicts in your case
    # do whatever you need to do here with processed
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is formatted in a very unusual and cumbersome way _ it's actually ***not*** in JSON format, it's instead a string literal representation of a Python data-structure — but it can be worked around using a [`ast.lister_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) *twice* as illustrated below. As you should be able to see from the output, the contents of each `alert` can noe be accessed by values of keys in a list of a dictionaries.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint


data = '[\n    {\n        "TimeRecorded": "2020-09-20T08:56:12Z",\n        "AlertName": "Alert1",\n        "Entities": "[\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Address\\": \\"160.160.100.2\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"ip\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"4\\",\\r\\n    \\"DnsDomain\\": \\"example.com\\",\\r\\n    \\"HostName\\": \\"MyMachine1\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"host\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"5\\",\\r\\n    \\"Name\\": \\"Tenant1\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"account\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n]"\n    },\n    {\n        "TimeRecorded": "2020-09-20T07:56:13Z",\n        "AlertName": "Alert2",\n        "Entities": "[\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Address\\": \\"160.160.100.1\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"ip\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"4\\",\\r\\n    \\"DnsDomain\\": \\"example.com\\",\\r\\n    \\"HostName\\": \\"MyMachine2\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"host\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"5\\",\\r\\n    \\"Name\\": \\"Tenant2\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"account\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n]"\n    },\n    {\n        "TimeRecorded": "2020-09-20T05:56:14Z",\n        "AlertName": "Alert3",\n        "Entities": "[\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Address\\": \\"160.160.100.3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"ip\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"4\\",\\r\\n    \\"DnsDomain\\": \\"example.com\\",\\r\\n    \\"HostName\\": \\"MyMachine3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"host\\"\\r\\n  },\\r\\n  {\\r\\n    \\"$id\\": \\"5\\",\\r\\n    \\"Name\\": \\"Tenant3\\",\\r\\n    \\"Type\\": \\"account\\"\\r\\n  }\\r\\n]"\n    }\n]'

data = literal_eval(data)
for alert in data:
    alert['Entities'] = literal_eval(alert['Entities'])

pprint(data, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
[{'TimeRecorded': '2020-09-20T08:56:12Z',
  'AlertName': 'Alert1',
  'Entities': [{'$id': '3', 'Address': '160.160.100.2', 'Type': 'ip'},
               {'$id': '4',
                'DnsDomain': 'example.com',
                'HostName': 'MyMachine1',
                'Type': 'host'},
               {'$id': '5', 'Name': 'Tenant1', 'Type': 'account'}]},
 {'TimeRecorded': '2020-09-20T07:56:13Z',
  'AlertName': 'Alert2',
  'Entities': [{'$id': '3', 'Address': '160.160.100.1', 'Type': 'ip'},
               {'$id': '4',
                'DnsDomain': 'example.com',
                'HostName': 'MyMachine2',
                'Type': 'host'},
               {'$id': '5', 'Name': 'Tenant2', 'Type': 'account'}]},
 {'TimeRecorded': '2020-09-20T05:56:14Z',
  'AlertName': 'Alert3',
  'Entities': [{'$id': '3', 'Address': '160.160.100.3', 'Type': 'ip'},
               {'$id': '4',
                'DnsDomain': 'example.com',
                'HostName': 'MyMachine3',
                'Type': 'host'},
               {'$id': '5', 'Name': 'Tenant3', 'Type': 'account'}]}]
```

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. The data I got was from my internal API system. Initially it had more keys and values and I shortened it further to just what's included in this post.

Comment: All I can go on is what you posted in your question — and the code in my answer works as claimed with no exception being raised. You must have changed the data improperly or left out some other detail.